# Why are different URLs rendering the same view in Django 2.0?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

Each time I run the command to start the server, `python manage.py runserver`, the first URL I load works just fine.  The problem comes when I try and open another page in my web app.  Whatever I loaded first after restarting the server is what renders when I try and load any other URL on the web app after it.

For example, If I load the page named 'personal' after restarting the server, it will load properly.  Then, if I try and load 'departmental,' the only thing that changes is the Title of the page and the URL in the address bar.  The page content remains the same.

Here is my urls.py file for the app:

```
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.login_page, name='login'),
  path('departmental', views.departmental_dashboard, name='home'),
  path('personal', views.personal_dashboard, name='personal'),
  path('admin_dash', views.admin_dashboard, name='admin'),
  path('adm/<username>', views.admin_individual, 
   name='admin_individual'),
]
```

I have found similar posts but they all date back to Django 1.X and URL configuration was changed significantly with the release of Django 2.0.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to add a slash at the end of each path

Comment: @NDZIEPatrickJoel That didn't work and is also something that was not required when Django 2.0 was released

Comment: It may be due to browser cache. reload the page with **hard-refresh**

Comment: Tried this @JerinPeterGeorge.. That's not the problem

Comment: Is this problem reproducible? If so, how could I?

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out the cause of the issue but I did manage to find a way to work around it.  I just created a new directory using `python manage.py startapp [appname]` I then moved all the files for one of the two pages that this issue was happening on into the new directory and updated my `urls.py` and `views.py` accordingly.